# Events are not displayed with timeline plugin

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-4

i try to display events with timeline plugin. I only see the start date. first image

```
    plugins: [ 'timeline' ],
    views: {
        timelineThreeYear: {
        type: 'timeline',
        duration: { year: 3 },
        buttonText: '3 ans'
      }
    },
    timeZone: 'local',
    height: 400,
    defaultView: 'timelineThreeYear',
    aspectRatio: 0.5,
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'timelineMonth,timelineYear,timelineThreeYear',
    },
```

[timeline view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfQD6.png)

with the same events, with daygrid plugin, i see the events.second image
i don't understand the problem.

```
plugins: [ 'dayGrid' ],
timeZone: 'UTC',
defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
editable: true,
```

[daygridMonth view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aIJD.png)

Comment: Could you please show us your events data (in JSON format) as well?

Comment: The reason I ask is that I suspect the issue really is that the events are so short that they only show up as a tiny speck in a view with such a long time period. But we need to confirm it, so we can make a demo to allow us to reproduce the issue. Once we can reproduce the issue fully, we stand a chance of being able to diagnose the cause and then fix it.

Comment: P.S. another thing - if you switch to, say, timelineMonth view (rather than 3 years view), do the events show properly? That would help us to understand if the issue relates to the scale of your view, or not.

Comment: My problem is due to core main.min.css. fc-event {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    font-size: .85em;
    line-height: 1.4;
    border-radius: 3px;
        border-top-left-radius: 3px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #3788d8;
        border-top-color: rgb(55, 136, 216);
        border-right-color: rgb(55, 136, 216);
        border-bottom-color: rgb(55, 136, 216);
        border-left-color: rgb(55, 136, 216);
        border-left-width: 1px;
} if i comment position: relative, i see my events.

Comment: can you invistigate this pb ? because every day, my environnement is updated and the core main.min.css is copied ...

Comment: to answer your question, my events are not so short. in my exemple, one of them start on 2019-02-01 and end in 2021-12-01

Comment: If you think there is a bug with fullCalendar's code, please raise a [bug report](https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs) as indicated on the website. Here on StackOverflow you can ask other fullCalendar users about tips, tricks and issues when trying to use fullCalendar, but we cannot help you with internal bugs in the product itself. As far as I know, the fullCalendar developers themselves do not follow this tag.